# generation of public,private and passphrase in pgp?

Tags: c#, bouncycastle

hi can anyone tell me how to generate pgp public, private and passphrase using bouncy castle in c#?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it :)

```
//DSA Key Pair Generator
DsaKeyPairGenerator a = new DsaKeyPairGenerator();

//DSA Key Parameter Generator
DsaParametersGenerator paramgen = new DsaParametersGenerator();

//Initialize Key Parameter Generator
paramgen.Init(512, 100, new SecureRandom());

//DSA KeyGeneration Parameters 
DsaKeyGenerationParameters param = new DsaKeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), paramgen.GenerateParameters());

//Initialize the Key Pair Generator
a.Init(param);

//The DSA Keys!
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keys = a.GenerateKeyPair();

//PGP PubKey
PgpPublicKey pub = new PgpPublicKey(Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.PublicKeyAlgorithmTag.Dsa, keys.Public, DateTime.Now);

//PGP PrivKey
PgpPrivateKey priv = new PgpPrivateKey(keys.Private, pub.KeyId);
```